# use css animation to detect positions in space invaders

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make a space invaders game, using only HTML, JS and CSS. The problem I'm having right now is with the `collisionDetection` function in JS. I have animated the enemies to go to right -> down -> left -> right etc. However, the code still thinks the they are in their staring position. Hence, the broken hitbox then. If I turn off the CSS animation `collisionDetection` works perfectly.

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="pilot"></div>
    <div id="missiles"></div>
    <div id="fiende"></div>
</div>

function collisionDetection() {
for (var enemy = fiende.length - 1; enemy >= 0; enemy--) {
    for (var missile = 0; missile < missiles.length; missile++) {
        if (
            missiles[missile].left >= fiende[enemy].left &&
            missiles[missile].left <= (fiende[enemy].left + 50) &&
            missiles[missile].top <= (fiende[enemy].top + 50) &&
            missiles[missile].top >= fiende[enemy].top
        ) {
            fiende.splice(enemy, 1);
            missiles.splice(missile, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit hard to explain so I'll give you my Github for the game: https://belminh.github.io/Projekt_2/html/space_invaders.html and here's the link to get access to all my files: https://github.com/BelminH/belminh.github.io/tree/master/Projekt_2

Answer (score 1):

I have viewed your code and find this code is the answer of your question:

**document.getElementById('fiende').style.animation = 'bevegelse 32s forwards'**

This code used css animation, and you couldn't find out real position of the fiendes.

Comment: But how do I fix the issue then? To I need to animate it in JS instead then?

Comment: Yes, you need to animate them in JS

Comment: I'm not experienced with animating in JS, is there a guide that fits my issue I could follow?

Comment: Use js like this: var direction = 1;
function drawFiende() {
    document.getElementById('fiende').innerHTML = '';
    if (fiende[0].left === [maxWidth]) {// maxWidth is the max left position
        direction = -1;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < fiende.length; i++) {
        fiende[i].left += direction * 2;
        fiende[i].top += 2;
        document.getElementById('fiende').innerHTML += `<div class='enemy' style='left:${fiende[i].left}px; top:${fiende[i].top}px'></div>`;
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    drawFiende();
}, 200);

Answer (score 1):

I Think too the problem comes from the css animation, it move the div fiende but not change the values in your js. Plus you may be must add the lateral movement in moveFiende() function.

Comment: What do you mean by "lateral movement " in moveFiende() function?

Comment: fiende[i].left, you change only the top

Answer (score 0):

You just made the animation but you aren't moving the enemy.

```
<div class="enemy" style="left:450px; top:75px"></div>
```

Values of your `"enemy"` div aren't changing, so the hitbox stays in the same place.

Comment: I did that in JS: var fiende = [
    { left: 250, top: 75 },
    { left: 350, top: 75 },
    { left: 450, top: 75 },
]; etc...

Comment: I think you should go into debugging in browser to see what I meant. And if I see correctly you aren't even calling the `moveFiende()` function.